# Where are media attributes/roles stored?

Tags: database, media-images, magento2.4.2, gallery-image

I was browsing through the DB, trying to find out where the media attributes of product-media-gallery-items are stored.
For clarification: They are called "Roles" in the Admin-Frontend and "mediaAttributes" when interacting with them in Code.

There is the catalog_product_entity_media_gallery table that holds all pictures and then there is the catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value table that holds information about the pictures, such as in which store-views they are placed and their position, but I wasn't able to figure out where those "Roles" are kept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *'roles'* are specific attributes: **image** (for Base role), **small_image** (for Small), **swatch_image** (for Swatch) and **thumbnail**.

You can find the IDs of these attributes by checking the `eav_attribute` table and according to their `backend_type`, you will find the values associated per product in the `catalog_product_entity_varchar` table. The records will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you once again for a great answer!

Comment: You are most welcome :) cheers!